# Reading white spaces from a text file

Tags: c++, xcode6, fstream

I am trying to read white space characters from a certain file and store them in an array position, but when i run the code i keep getting this thread:thread 1 exc_bad_access (code=exc_i386_gpflt). And i don't know what i am getting wrong. Using Xcode 6.4 btw.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<fstream>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;
const int COLS = 8;
const int ROWS = 8;
//Function Prototypes
void displayTop();
void displayNumColumn();
void displayNumRow();
int displayMenu();
void displayBoard();
char displayHelp();
void playGame(char player, int plB, int plW);
void goToMenu(char x);
int saveFile(char x, char board[][COLS], char player, int plB, int plW);
void loadGame();
void clearBoard();

//Global Variables
int num = 1;
char board [COLS][ROWS] = {

    ' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',
    ' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',
    ' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',
    ' ',' ',' ','W','B',' ',' ',' ',
    ' ',' ',' ','B','W',' ',' ',' ',
    ' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',
    ' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',
    ' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',

};

int main() {

    int choice = displayMenu();

    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            system("clear");
            clearBoard();
            displayBoard();
            break;
        case 2:
            loadGame();
            break;
        case 3:
            displayHelp();
            break;
        case 4:
            return 0;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Please enter a valid choice." << endl;
            break;
    }
    playGame('B', 2, 2);

}
//Function to draw and display the board
void displayBoard(){

    displayTop();
    num = 1;
    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++){

        displayNumRow();
        cout << "   |";

        for (int column = 0; column < COLS; column++){
            cout << board[row][column] << "   |";
        }
        cout << endl;
        displayTop();

    }

    displayNumColumn();

}
// Function to display a horizontal line
void displayTop(){

    cout << "    ";

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
        cout << "+----";
    }

    cout << endl;

}
//Function to display the alphabets column
void displayNumColumn(){

    cout << "   ";

    for( int i = 1; i <= COLS; i++ ) {
        cout << "    " << i ;
    }
}
//Function to display the numbers row
void displayNumRow(){

    if (num <= ROWS) {
        cout << num;
        num++;

    }
}
// Function to display the menu
int displayMenu(){

    int answer = 0;
    cout << "Othello\n\n"
    << "1.New Game\n2.Load Game\n3.Help\n4.Quit\nYour Choice: ";
    cin >> answer;
    system("clear");
    return answer;

}
// Function to display the help window
char displayHelp(){

    char answer = ' ';

    cout << "How to play Othello\n\nThe object of the game is to have the majority of your colour discs on the board at the end of the game.\n\nInput the cell where you want to place your disc in the form of (rowNumber columnNumber) without the bracket and includng the space.\n\nThe one with the most discs wins!!!!\n\nSo, are you ready to play? (y or n)\n\nYour Choice: ";
    cin >> answer;

    if (answer == 'y')
        displayBoard();
    else if (answer == 'n')
        displayHelp();
    else
        cout << "Invalid input" << endl << endl;;
    displayHelp();

    return answer;
}
// Function to act as the game engine
void playGame(char player, int plB, int plW){
    char x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    // Infinite for loop to keep switching between players and asking for moves
    for(;;){
        cout << "\n\nScore: W = " << plW << " B = " << plB;
        cout << "\nPlayer: " << player;
        cout << "\nPlease make your move : ";
        cin >> x;
        cin >> y;
        cout << endl;
        goToMenu(x);
        int xi = x -'0';
        // If condition to check for the validity of the input
        if (xi <= ROWS && y <= COLS && board[xi-1][y-1] == ' ' && cin.good()) {
            board[xi-1][y-1] = player;
            displayBoard();
        } else {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(100,'\n');
            if (saveFile(x, board, player, plB, plW)) {
                cout << "Game Saved" << endl;
                if (player == 'B') {
                    plB--;
                } else {
                    plW--;
                }
            } else {
                cout << "Invalid Input" << endl;
                if (player == 'B') {
                    plB--;
                } else {
                    plW--;
                }

            }

        }

        // If condition to always change the players and add one to their score
        if (player == 'B') {
            plB++;
            player = 'W';

        } else {
            plW++;
            player = 'B';
        }
    }

}

void goToMenu(char x){
    if (x == 'm') {
        main();
    }

}

int saveFile(char x, char board[][COLS], char player, int plB, int plW){
    ofstream savedGame("savedGame.txt");

    if (x == 's') {
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
                savedGame << board[i][j];

            }
        }

        savedGame << player;
        savedGame << plB;
        savedGame << plW;
    }else {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
//Again the same thread: thread 1 exc_bad_access (code=exc_i386_gpflt)
void loadGame(){
    char player;
    char plB;
    char plW;
    int blck;
    int wht;
    ifstream savedGame("savedGame.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            savedGame >> noskipws;
            savedGame >> board[i][j];
        }
    }
    savedGame >> player;
    savedGame >> plW;
    savedGame >> plB;
    blck = plB - '0';
    wht = plW - '0';
    displayBoard();
    playGame(player, blck, wht);

}

void clearBoard(){
    for (int i = 0; i <= ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= COLS; j++) {
            board[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
    board[3][3] = 'W';
    board[3][4] = 'B';
    board[4][3] = 'B';
    board[4][4] = 'W';
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: `i <= ROWS` <= that goes out of bounds of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is on the for loops, all of then have "i <= ROWS" so it will go beyond the array and so it throws an exception

```
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
```

And you are done

Comment: Well, you also need to change to `for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)` as well

Comment: wow thank you very much @Juan . But i still don't understand what you mean "it will go beyond the array". I'm sorry if this seems as a silly question, but i'm kind of a newbie in C++

Comment: Imagine that you hace this: int array [5];  It is a code that tells that the array has 5 elements of type int, only five. If you try to read the six int, that doesnt exist, you will read memory that you doesnt own because may have other variable that is not part of the array (an array is a succesion of blocks of memory). That is what you did in the for loop, you went beyond its limits and the compiler warnings you with an error because it is bad to have this on code

Comment: @Juan I've edited the loadGame function a little bit to read in more variables, but then it gave me the same exact thread again when i run the program